# h:commandLink refreshes the page before calling the action

Tags: jsf-2

I have a page with a logout button which is h:commandLink

```
<h:form>
                <div id="top-nav">
                    <div id="logout" style="float: right; margin-left: 10px;">

                        <h:commandLink styleClass="top-nav-btn"
                            action="#{adminLogoutBean.logout}"
                            rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.sessionMap['ccUserVO'] ne null}" value="Logout" immediate="true">
                            <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" /> 
                            </h:commandLink>


                    </div>


                        <div style="margin-left: -80px;  margin-top: 70px;">
                            <p style="float: left;margin-left: 10px;">Please
                                enter client VIN or EMAIL</p>
                            <br />
                            <h:inputText styleClass="menus txfld_border_no_image required email"
                                minlength="5" style="width:300px;clear:right;display:inline;"
                                id="loginEmail" value="#{callCenterAdminBean.searchText}" />
                            <span class="btn-wrap" id="get_enabled"> <h:commandButton type="submit"
                                    class="common_btn noprint submit" id="userlookup_btn" value="GET"
                                    action="#{callCenterAdminBean.userLookup}">

                                </h:commandButton> </span>
                            <span class="btn-wrap" id="get_disabled" style="display:none"> <h:commandButton type="submit"
                                    class="common_btn noprint submit" disabled='true' value="GET"
                                    action="#{callCenterAdminBean.userLookup}">

                            </h:commandButton> </span>
                        </div>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </div>

            </h:form>
```

When I click on Logout, I find the page refreshes first and then the action is called. Why does the page refresh? I want to call the bean method which will redirect to the login page using the navigation rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the navigation you don't need the ajax , just remove the

```
<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@none" />
```

And remove the `immediate="true"` cause I don't see any reason for you to use it in the following use case...